# Shell Script to GZIP files without overwrite .gz files

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, compression, gzip

I'm trying to create a shell script which receive as first parameter of a path to a folder which I would like to compress all files using `gzip` without overwrite the `.gz` files that already exist in this folder.

I don't know for which reason this script is not working properly:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER=$1

cd $FOLDER
for f in *.*; do
  if [ ! -f "$f.gz" ]; then
    echo "Compressing $f file..";
    gzip $f
  else
    echo "Not overwriting $f.gz";
  fi
done
```

Sometime it gets confused about if the file is a `.gz` file and don't compress it.

Comment: Small note: quotation is needed to handle spaces and other special characters in filenames, i.e. `cd "$FOLDER"` and `gzip "$f"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your criteria are wrong. `*.*` will return all files with extensions. For example, `foo.gz`. Now you're checking the following, in pseudocode:

```
if [ foo.gz.gz does not exist ]
    compress foo.gz to foo.gz.gz
else
    don't overwrite foo.gz.gz
```

So, your test command will *always* branch off to compressing something because the test will always evaluate to true. In the end you'll *always* overwrite your files, because `"$f.gz"` will expand to `foo.gz.gz`.

---

If your real requirement is to match everything but `.gz` files in your current directory, Bash has easier ways to do that, e.g. by using the `extglob` option and negation.

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER=$1

shopt -s extglob

cd "$FOLDER"
for f in !(*.gz); do
  if [[ ! -d "$f" ]]; then
    gzip "$f"
  fi
done
```

You can include a check for whether the file name returned isn't actually a directory—unless you want to compress directories as well.

---

But actually, Linux gives you better tools to find files matching certain criteria. To (recursively) find all files that don't end with `.gz` and compress them:

```
find /some/where -type f ! -iname '*.gz' -exec gzip '{}' \;
```

If you don't want recursion:

```
find /some/where -type f -maxdepth 1 ! -iname '*.gz' -exec gzip '{}' \;
```

Comment: Actually, `gzip` just exits with `gzip: test.gz already has .gz suffix -- unchanged` and status 0 when run on files that already has the extension. But it is unnecessary matching nevertheless, as you say, and the `[ ! -f ]` test in the question would also do unexpected things if there was a subdirectory with a dot in it that matched the glob. (You have left an `echo` statement in the first `find` example.)